# MySQL insert into unknown column in field list

Tags: java, mysql

I'm getting

> MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'UUID' in 'field list'

with this code:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO players (player_uuid , name , age , gender , bios) " +
            "VALUES ( `UUID` , " + " `TestName` , 8 , `Female` , `TestBios`)";
```

I have created the table already.

Comment: " + " `TestName` what is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not write your queries in that way, it is unsafe (SQL injections) and possibly a lot slower then the following method:

Use prepared statements for queries with variables in it:

```
String sql="INSERT INTO players (player_uuid , name , age , gender , bios) "+
" VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt=connection.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setString(1,"UUID");
pstmt.setString(2,"TestName");
pstmt.setint(3,8);
pstmt.setString(4,"Female");
pstmt.setString(5,"TestBios");
pstmt.execute();
pstmt.close();
```

The database will cache the execution plan of the prepared statement, this saves time the next time the same statement is used (pretty much regardless of the values however certain databases will adjust the plan based on the values).
With inserts the savings are minimal in most conditions, with selects the overall savings can be significant.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your values into quotation mark to treat them as a string.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO players (player_uuid , name , age , gender , bios) " +
        "VALUES ( 'UUID' , " + " 'TestName' , 8 , 'Female' , 'TestBios')";
```

The ` char is reserved for esacaping column names.

Answer (score 1):

You meant to say like below. Replace those backtique with singlequote

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO players (player_uuid , name , age , gender , bios) 
VALUES ( 'UUID' ,'TestName' , 8 , 'Female' , 'TestBios')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instated of your code. Error is occured because you didn't use single cote for string values in SQL query. Actually  best way to this is use PreparedStatement.

```
 String sql = "INSERT INTO players (player_uuid , name , age , gender , bios) "
            + "VALUES ( 'UUID' , " + " 'TestName' , 8 , 'Female' , 'TestBios')";
```